# Unique File name using system time in Java?

Tags: java

I want to use unique id for the files. How can I use system time to generate unique IDs in Java?

Comment: I don't want to use UUIDs. Is System.currentTimeInMillis guaranteed to be unique??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use System.currentTimeInMillis

or

java.util.UUID.randomUUID()

Comment: I don't want to use UUIDs. Is System.currentTimeInMillis guaranteed to be unique??

Comment: System.currentTimeInMillis -> "the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC."
You can append the loggedInUserName to it to guarantee uniqueness across concurrent sessions.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the [`UUID` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html).

Answer (score 6):

[UUID class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) is what you need.

**Sample implementation :**

```
public class RandomStringUUID {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
                String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();

                System.out.println("Random UUID String = " + randomUUIDString);
                System.out.println("UUID version       = " + uuid.version());
                System.out.println("UUID variant       = " + uuid.variant());
           }
      }
```

**Output :**

```
Random UUID String = 7dc53df5-703e-49b3-8670-b1c468f47f1f
UUID version       = 4
UUID variant       = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [`File.createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) which creates an empty file that doesn't collide with anything else on the file system.

You can use [`File.deleteOnExit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit--) to ensure that it's deleted when the program exits.

Comment: Yes. But that method "creates" a temp file, that in my case, is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be based on the system time?  Can't you just use a UUID?

```
java.util.UUID.randomUUID();
```